# How can I let others install my Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've made a simple script in Google Apps Script. The script builds forms based on a spreadsheet, the script itself is part of the spreadsheet. It adds a menu item. People would like to use it. They are non-technical people, so I would like to make the installation of my script as easy as possible. With 'installation' I mean a way to 'import' my script into their spreadsheet and automatically set up the needed triggers so the menu item becomes visible. It should be possible for anyone to install it.
I've been thinking of the following solutions:

- Publishing as an add-on: my script wouldn't qualify, and even then I can't wait for Google's approval.
- Copy-paste. I don't like this, it's way too complicated.

I've looked at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334751/how-do-i-share-a-script-i-wrote-with-my-co-workers-on-the-same-google-apps-accou, but the people wanting to install it are not on the same domain in my case. The question is also 3 years old.

**EDIT**: As it turns out, there doesn't seem to be a solution. I've filed a feature request  here: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4122&thanks=4122&ts=1403949074

Comment: Re the add-on route, last I heard add-on's don't support programmatically adding triggers anyhow. Re by copy/paste I guess you mean copying the script itself. You can also offer a link to the spreadsheet to use as a master copy and they could copy that.

Answer (score 0):

If your Google Account administrator allows you, you can share scripts/spreadsheets outside your organisation either by sharing directly with another person with a Google Account (Gmail or Google Apps) or by making it public (share with a link or published online).
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en

Keep in mind that if you use the Script Properties to store values, each time someone uses the shared script it will overwrite the values. In a shared context it is best to use User Properties instead. This way each user can store their own values.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties

Comment: Also if the script is made available online (Web App), make sure you set it up to run as the users. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. I've edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to import a script in an existing spreadsheet , the "normal" workflow is , in a way, the reverse process, that's to say create a sheet from an existing template that already has the script in it and start to work with that copy.

From your description I'm not sure this method could be useable but I'm afraid there is no other way if you want people who will be using it should not go into the script editor at all.

There would be a couple of functions to write that should run at install time and would create the triggers (if needed) and trigger the authorization process.

I made such a SS some time ago that needed authorizations and I added an "install" menu that made its use quite simple ([example here](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/calendar/calendar_edit_example) on a friendly hosting site).

I know this is probably not the answer you were expecting but it was definitely too long to fit in a comment anyway.

Comment: This is problematic. My script is part of a spreadsheet automatically generated by a form. The workflow of people wanting to use my script would be to first create a form, and then the spreadsheet is created automatically. This way it is impossible to put my script in a template. Also,  I've made this script in order to fix a particular problem raised after the data was collected, so the spreadsheets are already there.

Comment: As I said: " I know this is probably not the answer you were expecting" couldn't you create the sheet using a template with script?

Comment: I know that this question will probably remain unanswered for some time, until Google fixes it. But no, it's not possible in my situation. My script is part of a spreadsheet, and the spreadsheet is automatically created by the form. Unless you could tell the form to use a certain template when creating a spreadsheet, the form will never include any scripts in the spreadsheets it creates. The form is always created first in this workflow.

Comment: It should be possible to tell the form to use a spreadsheet created from a template... I didn't try but I'm pretty sure you can. Could you provide a schematic structure of your workflow in pseudo code (or in real code) ? so I could provide a more concrete answer ... thx

Comment: You're right, it's possible. While that doesn't solve the problem for newly created spreadsheets, it does partly solve the problem. It is quite a lot of work though.
Scheme: http://i.imgur.com/YNrqRP0.png

Comment: I meant to say that would *not* solve the problem for already created spreadsheets.